# How to check invocation of method of same class based on condition of other mock class

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Class to be tested:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void methodToTest(type param1, type param2) {
        boolean condtion = service.getCondtion(param1);
    
        if(condtion){
            this.newMethod(param2);
        }
    }
}
```

My test method():

```
public testClass{

    @InjectMocks
    MyClass myclass;

    @Mock
    Service service;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        when(service.getCondition(param)).thenReturn(true);
        myClassMock.methodToTest(param1);

        verify(myClassMock, times(1)).newMethod(param2);
    }

}
```

Instead of verifying the invocation, the flow is going inside the newMethod(). This is not required because it will create new requirements and more mocking and variable initialization.

Any workaround for this?

I am using JUnit 4.0

Edit: corrected the code

Comment: This question needs clarification. Firstly, you are not calling `methodToTest` in your test. You are calling some other method `updateParentHaltingCounter` with a different argument list. Secondly, the test code suggests you are mocking class under test (variable `myClassMock`)

Comment: Mockito does have an @Spy that allows mixing a mock and an actual instance, but I would STRONGLY  recommend against using that for this.  Instead, I would ask if `this.newMethod` is a sufficiently complex (or `methodToTest` sufficiently simple) for some refactoring to separate `newMethod` into a separate service.

Comment: Corrected the code. Also, the `newMethod` is written by someone else, so I cannot refactor that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't refactor the method you could use the subclass-and-override method (explained in Working Effectively with Legacy Code from Michael Feathers).

Subclass-and-override

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public TestClass{

    @InjectMocks
    MyClassTestDouble myclass;

    @Mock
    Service service;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        when(service.getCondition(param)).thenReturn(true);
        myClassMock.methodToTest(param1);

        assertEquals(1, myclass.newMethodCalls);
    }

}
class MyClassTestDouble extends MyClass {
  int newMethodCalls = 0;
  
  public MyClassTestDouble(Service service){
    super(service);
  }
  
  @Override
  void newMethod(type param){
    newMethodCalls +=1;
  }
}
```